What are the best advanced techniques to perfect pronunciation for subtle English phonemes in PTE Speaking?
I'm struggling with precise sounds like /ɪ/ vs. /i:/ and connected speech. Any expert tips or resources for advanced learners?

Please provide some examples

And note that asking for external/third-party resources is off-topic (but you can find a list of those on our meta site here).

You should ask on English Language Learners or Language Learning SE if your question is about learning English.

John Trim, An Illustrated Guide to English Pronunciation on Youtube.
